# AWS MSK - Brokers going out of service all of a sudden

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

We had setup an MSK cluster with 3 brokers (each have 2 GB storage). The cluster was working fine for first day, then all of a sudden it stopped consuming messages on 2nd day even though there was no config change. The error we were getting at producer and consumer level was **Give up sending metadata request since no node is available**. Also we were not able to connect to the brokers thereafter.

While troubleshooting, we came across this link- **https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/msk-cluster-connection-issues/** . We assume, it may be due to disk utilization by looking at the cloudwatch metrics data.

We want to follow best practices as shown here **https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/bestpractices.html#bestpractices-monitor-disk-space** but as MSK doesn't provide command line support, we are not able to flush data from brokers and also not able to restart it.

It would be great if we get some advice on the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried scaling up the brokers storage and see if they are able to restart?

Comment: Yes we have increased size to 20 GB . But there is no option to restart it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-reboot-broker.html that doesn't work I assume

Comment: Thanks GerardGarcia. Tried it . The clusters started working after that. We did not notice the option for rebooting at the bottom.